# How to use bult-in spellchecker of Electron 8.x in Webviews

Tags: electron

Electron v8.x introduced built-in [spellchecker](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/20692). It get activated by setting spellcheck option in webPreferences in [BrowserWindow API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) to true. I would like to know whether it is possible to use this in webviews in electron. If so, how to use it.